# How to redirect url from bloggger to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, blogger

Good evening, friends of the forum.

I need your help to be able to redirect url from blogger to wordpress

Redirect url blogger:

www.dominio.moda/2017/07/articulo-de-ejemplo.html

to url wordpress:

www.dominio.moda/category/articulo-de-ejemplo

At first use:

Source URL /(\dd) /(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*).html

Target URL /% category% / $ 3

But it is not working well.

I'm using the Redirections plugins
 
Please let me know the correct way to do the redirection.

Also, in wordpress I have the custom url structure
  www.dominio.moda/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: What is the exactly the purpose? if the domain is changed, the links won't work. You could export from blogger and import to wordpress. Or like described in this link http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-switch-from-blogger-to-wordpress-without-losing-google-rankings/.

Comment: Good afternoon.
Apparently you do not understand me.

Migrating from blogger to wordpress I already did.

Now, I want to redirect with a 301 old blogger url to new ones found in wordpress.

Comment: @JhonnySanz There are plugins to help with this - https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-301-redirect/